# Can't launch vlc from apache using php

Tags: php, apache, vlc

I have a problem when I want to launch VLC from Apache using PHP. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 (It works with Archlinux).

```
Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) Server
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3 with Suhosin-Patch
```

I launched Apache with my own user.

Code:

```
<?php
$foo = system('/usr/bin/cvlc');
echo $foo;
?>
```

`$foo` is empty.
when I launch VLC from command line it works.
Simple `touch foo` works.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more about your setup? Is this running on a server, or on a local machine?

Comment: I'm on a local machine. Do you need some other informations?

Comment: Try what happens with a `export DISPLAY=:0.0;/usr/bin/cvlc 2>&1;`

Comment: When I try in a php script "exec('export DISPLAY=:0.0;/usr/bin/cvlc 2>&1;');" firefox can't finish to load the page

Comment: You'll probably also need to do an xhost +localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP 5.2.9 or less.

Problem happened to me in xampp 1.7.4 I replaced it by xampp 1.7.1 cvlc and it worked.

Hope this info useful, if it works for you I want to know the reason for that.